# Samsung 980 PRO confirmed faulty - Need to get a few video files off

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, file-corruption, samsung-ssd

I have a 2TB Samsung 980 PRO which has been confirmed faulty by samsung, it fails the samsung magician diagnostic software without even completing.

I assume the drive has some bad sectors, I've managed to recover the majority of files off the drive, but I have 3 or 4 MP4 Video files around 2-3GB in size which just refuse to be copied off.

I tried uploading them, zipping them, moving them to multiple different drives, and it always fails stating "Can't Read from the Source File or Disk."

I had a few other files that would not copy with the above error message but I managed to compress with 7zip and copy off.

The thing is the files play just fine in MPC or VLC so they don't seem (fully?) Corrupt.

Is there a software or method I can use to possibly move these files off the drive?

Answer (score 1):

If VLC will play them, how about getting it to transcode to another drive?

Not something I've ever actually done, but VLC has full instructions - https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/

Basically,

1. In VLC, go to "Media >> Convert / Save..." (Ctrl+R).
2. Add the input file(s) or stream(s) you want to transcode. Press "Convert / Save".
3. In the "Convert" windows specify the destination file name (including file extension - e.g. on Windows "C:\out.mp3").
4. Select the desired codec from the profile list. To check/edit the settings of a given profile press the "Edit selected profile" button.  Profiles can also be added/deleted.
5. Press "Start".

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

Best: Clone the drive for example (assuming Windows) like so https://youtu.be/32GJr39O744. Then extract files from the clone/disk image file. The free version of the tool in the video (DMDE) is probably all you need.

Second best in general, but perhaps more convenient in this situation, since it's just a few files 'Unstoppable Copier' might do the job: https://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29.

> The thing is the files play just fine in MPC or VLC so they don't seem
> (fully?) Corrupt.

If a couple of bad sectors happened in the actual data (mdat atom) then files will probably play just fine. If moov atom would be affected the file probably won't play. But even that is often 'fixable'.

Comment: Thanks this is good information, I am using Unstoppable Copier and it's copying a lot of corrupt bytes, but hasn't stopped. Is there a way to repair the files afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps. I often repair MP4 video but then there has to be something there that can be repaired. Plenty times people send me MP4's filled with zeros, nothing to repair there.